# How to use MatLab to read out text from this specific website to analyse music preference

Tags: matlab, web, extract, wget

So there is an annual radio event going on in The Netherlands called the "Top2000", where people can vote for their favorite artists and songs. I thought it would be cool to analyse the music & artist preference. For this I need to read out the artists/songs on voting lists that are shared with me per URL, like for example [this](https://stem.nporadio2.nl/top2000/share/0c3c6205692b2a36462d3f4907bb2eadbf27afb6) one. I already tried webread, urlread and wget to download the webpage, as follows:

```
url = 'https://stem.nporadio2.nl/top2000/share/c93732c2f20c266970eba7447931f25d865407ea'
Data1 = webread(url);
Data2 = urlread(url);
command = ['wget --no-check-certificate --page-requisites ' url];
system( command );
```

But all they ever output are HTML elements without any mention of artists or songs, which are clearly shown when navigating to said URL. Does anyone have an idea or hint on how to extract this info from this website? Thanks in advance! Note: I do not ask how to strip away the HTML elements. However, the actual information I am looking for seemingly is just not there at all using the methods above.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking properly at your website, I suspect the elements you want are dynamically loaded (e.g. by JavaScript). Since the JavaScript will not run during your WGET etc, that's why you can't see them since all that does is grab the HTML of the website.

I know this is a Matlab problem, but I highly recommend [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) on Python to solve your problem. With Selenium, the program can wait till the webpage fully loads, then grab the correct elements you need. It is super simple, you can check out this [tutorial](http://stanford.edu/~mgorkove/cgi-bin/rpython_tutorials/Scraping_a_Webpage_Rendered_by_Javascript_Using_Python.php).

If you prefer not to use Python, you can find the actual URL used by your website's Javascript to grab the Artists/Songs list (I took a quick look at the website and the artists seem to be loaded with `main.js`). I found this line in `main.js` that hints that the function is loading the list here:

```
h = null !== n ? n : {
                    _id: "0",
                    _source: {
                        id: 0,
                        artist: s,
                        title: l,
                        image: d.freeChoiceImage
                    }
                };
```

From here, you need to trace where `s` and `l` are loaded from, which will eventually lead you to the correct database URL. As you can see, this is starting to get way more complicated, whereas with Selenium you can solve your problem with just a few lines of code.